# ingresar el mismo input en otros dos inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo tres formularios distintos en Js, comparten solo un mismo valor al comienzo, el valor "deuda total", a partir de este valor se generan calculos diferentes en cada formulario.- 
Quiero poder ingresar el valor en un solo inmput y que se replique de forma automatica en los otros dos formularios.- probé con keyup y con unas opciones que brindaban acá pero no realice el cambio... 
Esta es parte del script 1 -Escribo en el imput deudaTotalsinquita

```
$('#calcularsinquita').on('keyup keypress change', function(e){
var deudaTotalsinquita,
    numeroCuotassinquita,
    importeCuotassinquita,
    pHonorariossinquita,
    honorariossinquita,
    cuotaHonorariossinquita,
    totalFinalsinquita,
    totalCuotasinquita,
    resumensinquita,
    pluralsinquita;

var needsValidationForms = $('#sinquita_form');
// Loop over them and prevent submission
var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(needsValidationForms, function(form) {
  if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
  }else{
    deudaTotalsinquita = parseInt($('#deudaTotalsinquita').val());
```

Una vez que ingreso el valor en el input deudatotalsinquita, necesito que el mismo valor se replique en los siguientes inputs, que pertenecen a otros formularios, en este caso, la etiqueta "deudaToal"

```
$('#calcular').on('keyup keypress change', function(e){
var deudaTotal,
quita,
descuento,
saldoParcial,
entrega,
saldoFinal,
numeroCuotas,
importeCuotas,
pHonorarios,
honorarios,
cuotaHonorarios,
totalFinal,
totalCuota,
resumen,
plural;

var needsValidationForms = $('#conquita_form');
// Loop over them and prevent submission
var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(needsValidationForms, function(form) {
  if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
  }else{
    deudaTotal = parseInt($('#deudaTotal').val());
```

y en este ultimo caso en la etiqueta "deudaTotalr

```
 $('#calcularRefi').on('keyup keypress change', function(e){
var deudaTotalr,
anticipo,
valoranticipo, 
saldofinanciar, 
tna,
numeroCuotasrefi,
ingresostt,
relacionci,
porcentajehonosrefi,
honorariosrefi,
anticipohonos,
cantidadcuotashonorariosrefi,
importecuotahonosrefi,
sumatotalrefiyhonos,
sumacuotahonosycuotarefi,
resumenrefi,
sumaanticipo;

var needsValidationFormsR = $('#refinanciacion');
// Loop over them and prevent submission
var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(needsValidationFormsR, function(form) {
  if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
  form.classList.add('was-validated');
   }else{
  deudaTotalr = parseInt($('#deudaTotalr').val());
```

Probé con keyup y con oninput en html de forma directa pero no toma el valor... no se si en realidad se puede hacer por eso consulto... 
en resumen.. ingreso en la etiqueta "deudaTotalsinquita" un valor y necesito que al mismo tiempo ese valor se escriba en "deudatotal" y en "deudatotalr".-

> 

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
  <div class="card shadow bg-light rounded mt-2 mx-auto">
  <h5 class="card-header text-white bg-dark">CALCULADOR DE CUOTAS SIN QUITA</h5>
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate id="sinquita_form" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="card-body">

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="deudaTotalsinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Deuda Total</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" name="deudaTotalsinquita" id="deudaTotalsinquita" min="1" step="0.001" placeholder="Deuda Total" required >
  <div class="invalid-tooltip">
  Ingrese el saldo deudor.
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="numeroCuotassinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Cantidad de Cuotas</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>N°</strong></div>
  </div>
  <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="numeroCuotas" id="numeroCuotassinquita" required>
    <option value="1">1 Cuota</option>
    <option value="2">2 Cuotas</option>

  </select>
  <div class="invalid-tooltip">
  Ingrese las cuotas.
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="importeCuotassinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Importe Cuotas</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="number" name="importeCuotassinquita" id="importeCuotassinquita" readonly>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="pHonorariossinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Porcentaje Honorarios</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>%</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" name="pHonorariossinquita" id="pHonorariossinquita" min="15" max="100" step="1" value="18" required>
  <div class="invalid-tooltip">
  Ingrese el porcentaje de honorarios.
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="honorariossinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Total Honorarios</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="number" name="honorariossinquita" id="honorariossinquita" readonly>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="cuotaHonorariossinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Cuota Honorarios</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="number" name="cuotaHonorariossinquita" id="cuotaHonorariossinquita" readonly>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="totalFinalsinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Total Deuda y Honorarios</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="number" name="totalFinalsinquita" id="totalFinalsinquita" readonly>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="alert alert-primary mt-4 mb-2" id="resumensinquita"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="calcular" id="calcularsinquita">Calcular</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="copiar" id="copiarsinquita">Copiar</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" name="borrar" id="borrarsinquita">Borrar</button>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <BR>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
  <div class="card shadow bg-light rounded mt-2 mx-auto">
  <h5 class="card-header text-white bg-dark">CALCULADOR DE CUOTAS CON QUITA DE INTERES</h5>
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate id="conquita_form" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="card-body">

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="deudaTotal" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Deuda Total</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" name="deudaTotal" id="deudaTotal" min="1" step="0.001" placeholder="Deuda Total" required>
  <div class="invalid-tooltip">
  Ingrese el saldo deudor.
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="quita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Porcentaje Quita</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>%</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" name="quita" id="quita" min="0" max="40" step="1" placeholder="Quita Deuda" value="20" required>
  <div class="invalid-tooltip">
  Ingrese el porcentaje de quita.
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="descuento" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Monto Quita</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="text" name="descuento" id="descuento" readonly>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="saldoFinal" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Saldo Parcial</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="text" name="saldoParcial" id="saldoParcial" readonly>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="entrega" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Entrega a Cuenta</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" name="entrega" id="entrega" min="0" step="1" placeholder="Entrega a Cuenta" value="0">
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="saldoFinal" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Saldo Final</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="text" name="saldoFinal" id="saldoFinal" readonly>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="numeroCuotas" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Cantidad de Cuotas</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>N°</strong></div>
  </div>
  <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="numeroCuotas" id="numeroCuotas" required>
    <option value="1">1 Cuota</option>
    <option value="2">2 Cuotas</option>
    <option value="3">3 Cuotas</option>

  </select>
  <div class="invalid-tooltip">
  Ingrese las cuotas.
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="importeCuotas" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Importe Cuotas</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="text" name="importeCuotas" id="importeCuotas" readonly>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="pHonorarios" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Porcentaje Honorarios</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>%</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" name="pHonorarios" id="pHonorarios" min="0" max="100" step="1" placeholder="Porcentaje Honorarios" value="15" required>
  <div class="invalid-tooltip">
  Ingrese el porcentaje de honorarios.
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row mb-2">
  <label for="honorarios" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Total Honorarios</label>
  <div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="text" name="honorarios" id="honorarios" readonly>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>



  <div class="alert alert-primary mt-4 mb-2" id="resumen"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="calcular" id="calcular">Calcular</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="copiar" id="copiar">Copiar</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" name="borrar" id="borrar">Borrar</button>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: podrias colocar la estructura html para tener un ejemplo minimo verificable!

Comment: agregúe el html de 2 formularios... dejé fuera el último formulario ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero no necesitas todo esos eventos con `keyup` es suficiente!

## ejemplo:

```js
// inicializamos las variables
var  numeroCuotas = 0,
input = 0,
pHonorarios,
// selectores
importeCuotassinquita = 0,
honorariossinquita = 0,
cuotaHonorariossinquita = 0,
totalFinalsinquita =0;

 function updateInputs(){
// validamos que este definida la variable // cualquiera funciona todas se configuran en el mismo sitio!
  if(totalFinalsinquita){
       // aqui ya haces tus formulas
      importeCuotassinquita.val(input / numeroCuotas);

      honorariossinquita.val(input  * ("0."+pHonorarios ));
      cuotaHonorariossinquita.val(input);
      totalFinalsinquita.val(input  * ("1."+pHonorarios ));
}
   }
$('#pHonorariossinquita').on('change', function(e) {
let self = $(this);
pHonorarios = +self.val();

updateInputs();
})         
$('#deudaTotalsinquita').on('keyup', function(e) {
        // this
        let self = $(this);

        // buscamos a unos de los padres
        let parent = self.parents("div .card-body"); 

        // el simbolo +  al principio hace un cast a int automatico
        // buscamos los input que nos interesan
        // seleccionamos por el name "selectores avanzados de css"

        input = +self.val();
        pHonorarios = +parent.find('.mb-2 input[name="pHonorariossinquita"]').val();
        // si esta definido numeroCuotas sera igual a numero de cuotas de lo contrario tomara el valor del selected
         numeroCuotas = +( numeroCuotas ? numeroCuotas : parent.find('select[name="numeroCuotas"]').val() );

        // input a cambiar los valores
        importeCuotassinquita = parent.find('.mb-2 input[name="importeCuotassinquita"]');
        honorariossinquita = parent.find('.mb-2 input[name="honorariossinquita"]');
         cuotaHonorariossinquita = parent.find('.mb-2 input[name="cuotaHonorariossinquita"]');
        totalFinalsinquita = parent.find('.mb-2 input[name="totalFinalsinquita"]');
 // actualizamos los inputs
 updateInputs();
 });
 
$('#numeroCuotassinquita').on('change', function(e) {
 let self = $(this);
 numeroCuotas = +self.val();
 // actualizamos los inputs
 updateInputs();
})
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
                    <div class="card shadow bg-light rounded mt-2 mx-auto">
                        <h5 class="card-header text-white bg-dark">CALCULADOR DE CUOTAS SIN QUITA</h5>
                        <form class="needs-validation" novalidate id="sinquita_form" autocomplete="off">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="form-row mb-2">
                                    <label for="deudaTotalsinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Deuda Total</label>
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- aqui-->
                                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" name="deudaTotalsinquita" id="deudaTotalsinquita" min="1" step="0.001" placeholder="Deuda Total" required>
                                            <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                                                Ingrese el saldo deudor.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row mb-2">
                                    <label for="numeroCuotassinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Cantidad de Cuotas</label>
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-text"><strong>N°</strong></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="numeroCuotas" id="numeroCuotassinquita" required>
                                                <option value="1">1 Cuota</option>
                                                <option value="2">2 Cuotas</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                                                Ingrese las cuotas.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row mb-2">
                                    <label for="importeCuotassinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Importe Cuotas</label>
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="number" name="importeCuotassinquita" id="importeCuotassinquita" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row mb-2">
                                    <label for="pHonorariossinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Porcentaje Honorarios</label>
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-text"><strong>%</strong></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" name="pHonorariossinquita" id="pHonorariossinquita" min="15" max="100" step="1" value="18" required>
                                            <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                                                Ingrese el porcentaje de honorarios.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row mb-2">
                                    <label for="honorariossinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Total Honorarios</label>
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="number" name="honorariossinquita" id="honorariossinquita" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row mb-2">
                                    <label for="cuotaHonorariossinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Cuota Honorarios</label>
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="number" name="cuotaHonorariossinquita" id="cuotaHonorariossinquita" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row mb-2">
                                    <label for="totalFinalsinquita" class="col-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Total Deuda y Honorarios</label>
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <div class="form-row input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-text"><strong>$</strong></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-info text-white not-allowed" tabIndex="-1" type="number" name="totalFinalsinquita" id="totalFinalsinquita" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="alert alert-primary mt-4 mb-2" id="resumensinquita"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="calcular" id="calcularsinquita">Calcular</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="copiar" id="copiarsinquita">Copiar</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" name="borrar" id="borrarsinquita">Borrar</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Buen dia... por lo que entiendo de tu respuesta, con esto, no necesito tener todas las funciones que puse antes... solo una y llamar a tos inputs con keyup... es correcto?

Comment: Perdón, pero no se como poner que se divida por las cuotas que voy ingresando, y cuando modifico el porcentaje de honorarios da los resultados con muchos decimales...

Comment: puedes usar el metodo toFixed() ejemplo `var num = 1.299999999999999; num.toFixed(2);`

Comment: No entiendo como funciona esto que me enviaste... porque por ejemplo, si quiero dividir el importe total por las cuotas, no lo toma, seguramente porque no lo se escribir. y lo mismo con los honorarios, los tengo que dividir en las mismas cuotas... con lo que ya enviaste, si modifico las cuotas, no modifica los valores... Decime donde puedo leer sobre esto. Gracias

Comment: let totalFinalsinquita = parent.find('.mb-2 input[name="totalFinalsinquita"]');
        let numeroCuotas = parent.find('.mb-2 input[name="numeroCuotas"]');

        // test
  // aqui ya haces tus formulas
        importeCuotassinquita.val(input / numeroCuotas );
lo puse asi y no divide...

Comment: pusiste el numero de cuatas a 2 en 1 es igual :V

Comment: porque necesito que el valor de deuda total se divida por las cuotas y el resultado vaya en importeCuotassinquita - pero ademas necesito que el valor honorarios haga la misma division y el resultado vaya en cuotaHonorariossinquita -. uso el mismo selector de cuotas para ambas divisiones...No entiendo...

Comment: si cambio las cuotas en el ejemplo acá, tampoco divide las cuotas, pone el mismo valor del primer imput. De todas formas, mi consulta iba sobre la sintaxis, para entender como funciona, porque yo tengo 3 formularios que debería modificar.

Comment: creo que ya hice el cambio que requerias y la idea es la misma para todos los inputs solo debes tomar los datos de cada uno si la estructura es igual para todos por lo que vi! lo que cambiaria solo es el name del input o del select saludos!

Comment: Genial!!! Ahora Si!!! No molesto mas !!! muchas gracias